# Delphi changing Chars in string - missunderstood behavior - XE3

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a code on some kind of encoder/decoder, and can't figure out the strange behavior for more than 2 days now... I hope someone might understand and explain to me why is happening, whatever it is...

Here's the main code, which does the thing (I removed the form's info, buttons etc, just the core to avoid garbage)

```
unit Encoder;
//
interface
//

var
  Enc : array [1..71] of Record
    Char: Char;
    Encr: string;
    Enc: array [1..5] of Char;
  end;
  EncodeBuffer: TStringList;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TEncrypter.Encode;
var
  s, t, u, h, h2, h3, h4, h5: integer;
begin
  s := EncodeBuffer.Count;
  h := 0;
  h2 := 1;
  h3 := 2;
  h4 := 3;
  h5 := 4;

  while h < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Chars[u], EncodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Chars[u], 1));
      end;
    end;
    h := h + 5;
  end;

  while h2 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Chars[u], EncodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Chars[u], 2));
      end;
    end;
    h2 := h2 + 5;
  end;

  while h3 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Chars[u], EncodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Chars[u], 3));
      end;
    end;
    h3 := h3 + 5;
  end;

  while h4 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Chars[u], EncodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Chars[u], 4));
      end;
    end;
    h4 := h4 + 5;
  end;

  while h5 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Chars[u], EncodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Chars[u], 5));
      end;
    end;
    h5 := h5 + 5;
  end;
end;

procedure TEncrypter.Decode;
var
  s, t, u, h, h2, h3, h4, h5: integer;
begin
  s := EncodeBuffer.Count;
  h := 0;
  h2 := 1;
  h3 := 2;
  h4 := 3;
  h5 := 4;

  while h < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Chars[u], DecodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Chars[u], 1));
      end;
    end;
    h := h + 5;
  end;

  while h2 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Chars[u], DecodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Chars[u], 2));
      end;
    end;
    h2 := h2 + 5;
  end;

  while h3 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Chars[u], DecodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h3].Chars[u], 3));
      end;
    end;
    h3 := h3 + 5;
  end;

  while h4 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Chars[u], DecodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h4].Chars[u], 4));
      end;
    end;
    h4 := h4 + 5;
  end;

  while h5 < s do
  begin
    t := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Length;
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5] := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Chars[u], DecodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h5].Chars[u], 5));
      end;
    end;
    h5 := h5 + 5;
  end;
end;

function TEncrypter.EncodeChar(Sign: Char; Encoder: integer) : Char;
var
  t: integer;
begin
  for t := 1 to 71 do
  begin
    if Sign = enc[t].Char then
    begin
      Result := enc[t].Enc[Encoder];
      Break;
    end
    else
      Result := Sign;
  end;
end;

function TEncrypter.DecodeChar(Sign: Char; Encoder: integer) : Char;
var
  t: integer;
begin
  for t := 1 to 71 do
  begin
    if Sign = enc[t].Enc[Encoder] then
    begin
      Result := enc[t].Char;
      Break;
    end
    else
      Result := Sign;
  end;
end;
```

I have an Enc array created on `FormCreate` event, which fills `Enc[1 to 71].Char` and `Enc[1 to 71].Enc[1 to 5]` with random char order;

The code is made (or at least should be) so that it uses different encode list from array for each 5th line (line 1 `enc[x].enc[1]`, line 2 `enc[x].enc[2]`, and then line 5 `enc[x].enc[5]`, and line 6 back to `enc[x].enc[1]` and so on...)

If I encode 5 lines from Memo1, which are:

```
Memo1
Memo2
Memo3
Memo4
Memo5
```

I get some random words with 5 chars each, however when decoding it back, I get returned

```
Memo1
Memo2
memo3
Memo4
Memo5
```

(notice the lower m letter in 3rd line);

If I then encode this again, I get the exact same encoded stringlist as in the first case, only that here, the 3rd line's 3rd char! (wtf?) is changed with the same as the firstone is.
so, for Memo3 I get `q7M0e`, and for memo3 I get `q7q0e`, which makes no sense to me, as the position of a char should be the same, as far as I understand by the code.

Is there anything I'm missing here, noticable in the code above??

Comment if there's a need for me to paste the complete form's (unit's) code and exe example, I'll give it on a web and link to that...

Edit:

Here's the "key", by which I'm encoding/decoding: http://txt.do/128b

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you are doing here and even more difficult to understand why you are doing it. Why not use an existing, well-researched (secure) encryption method?

Comment: I'm trying to have my own encode/decode procedure, and understand why it's failing to work. It's not about the encoding itself, but more of an understanding why would some logic fail to operate correct way, why I'm asking this... :/

Comment: Maybe could DRY the code a bit, and don't use magic numbers (like 71).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thanks for edit..

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand the 71 is not a magic number. That's the number of char's I have, which I change. That's the length of Enc array of record...

Comment: What is your underlying problem?

Comment: @Just: I know. But it is much better to write `High(Enc)` instead of `73`.

Comment: @David Heffernan The underlying problem is that it replaces chars kinda randomly, but always with the same mistake. Such as, if I pass the 3rd line string as "Memo3" to encode, (the 3rd line encodes with the given "encoder" integer variable as 3, so searches through Enc[x].Enc[3]), it encodes as it should, but when decoding, it returns "memo3", with lowercase... with encoding that, it changes the decoded string back again into something 3rd... so, don't really know what is happening there. That's why I asked if there's any obvious mistake in a code. I guess it might be what Remy is saying...

Comment: I'll try his solution out today to see if it solves the strange behavior...

Comment: No. I mean, what is the code trying to do? What encoding is this?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand ok I see your point here. Well, it's just a matter of habit, since I don't use it much globally so never encountered a problem with forgetting to set every variable with new value, if changed...
I know it's a bat habit, though..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  It's custom encoding of a text; Basically the code is trying to change every char of a text file with another char which is defined as a replacement (5 for a, z for b, O for c, etc..), but dependent on the line of the strings; each line is encoded with a different "key" (1st 5 for a, 2nd t for a, 3rd P for a... etc, as defined in a enc[x].Char and enc[x].Enc[1 to 5] key record), for 5 lines; 6th is encoded the same as 1st, 7th as 2nd, and so on. That's why there are h, h1, h2, h3 and h4 variables in my code (or, Remy used h mod 5, which is a smart choice I never knew about...)

Comment: You code will be very inefficient. In any case, I cannot understand why you would not use build in crypto.

Comment: I believe that, although when coming to only encrypt and decrypt a Stringlist of a single txt file loaded at run, and saved on terminate, it doesn't work out so inefficient. The reason why not use build in crypto is the main point in learning to do something by myself, as well as an option to change the key only, based on an application version, volume serial, etc...  this is something I managed to (almost, now thanks to remy fully) get done and working. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach.

One problem is with your use of `String.Replace()`, which replaces **ALL** occurrences of one `Char` with another `Char`.  Once you replace a given `Char`, you can potentially replace that same index with a different value later on in your loops, thus trashing your data while you are looping.

Another problem is your decoding logic.  You are allowing each un-encoded `Char` to be encoded with one of 5 different `Char`s.  If those encoded `Char` values are duplicated at all across your `Enc[1..71].Enc` array for the same value of `Encoder`, you will not be able to know which `Enc[1..71].Char` to use for decoding.  It is not enough that your arrays are simply random, but they also need to be unique for the same value of `Encoder`.

Also, your loops are redundant and overly complicated.  They can be greatly simplified.

Try something more like this instead:

```
function TEncrypter.EncodeChar(Sign: Char; Encoder: integer) : Char;
var
  t: integer;
begin
  for t := 1 to 71 do
  begin
    if Sign = Enc[t].Char then
    begin
      Result := Enc[t].Enc[Encoder];
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := Sign;
end;

function TEncrypter.DecodeChar(Sign: Char; Encoder: integer) : Char;
var
  t: integer;
begin
  for t := 1 to 71 do
  begin
    if Sign = Enc[t].Enc[Encoder] then
    begin
      Result := Enc[t].Char;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := Sign;
end;

procedure TEncrypter.Encode;
var
  t, u, h: integer;
  s: String;
begin
  for h := 0 to EncodeBuffer.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h];
    t := Length(s);
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        s[u+1] := EncodeChar(s[u+1], (h mod 5) + 1);
      end;
      EncodeBuffer.Strings[h] := s;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TEncrypter.Decode;
var
  t, u, h: integer;
  s: String;
begin
  for h := 0 to EncodeBuffer.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h];
    t := Length(s);
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        s[u+1] := DecodeChar(s[u+1], (h mod 5) + 1);
      end;
      EncodeBuffer.Strings[h] := s;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

```
// FormCreate

var
  I, J, K, L: Integer;
  Temp: Array[1..71] of Char;
  NumInTemp: Integer;
begin
  ...

  // initialize Enc[].Char as needed...
  for I := 1 to 71 do
  begin
    Enc[I].Char := ...;
  end;

  // uniquely initialize each Enc[].Enc array for one value of Encoder...
  for I := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    for J := 1 to 71 do
      Temp[J] := ...; // must be unique for this iteration of I...
    NumInTemp := 71;

    // randomly assign Temp array to Enc[I].Enc array
    for J := 1 to 71 do
    begin
      K := 1 + Random(NumInTemp);
      Enc[J].Enc[I] := Temp[K];
      for L := K+1 to NumInTemp do
        Temp[L-1] := Temp[L];
      Dec(NumInTemp);
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

If you then expand your arrays to allow all printable ASCII characters, not just 71 of them, then the code gets a little simpler:

```
var
  Enc : array [32..126] of Record
    Char: Char;
    Encr: string;
    Enc: array [1..5] of Char;
  end;

  EncodeBuffer: TStringList;

function TEncrypter.EncodeChar(Sign: Char; Encoder: integer) : Char;
var
  t: integer;
begin
  if (Sign >= #32) and (Sign <= #126) then
    Result := Enc[Ord(Sign)].Enc[Encoder]
  else
    Result := Sign;
end;

function TEncrypter.DecodeChar(Sign: Char; Encoder: integer) : Char;
var
  t: integer;
begin
  for t := Low(Enc) to High(Enc) do
  begin
    if Sign = Enc[t].Enc[Encoder] then
    begin
      Result := Enc[t].Char;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := Sign;
end;

procedure TEncrypter.Encode;
var
  u, h: integer;
  s: String;
begin
  for h := 0 to EncodeBuffer.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h];
    for u := Low(s) to High(s) do
      s[u] := EncodeChar(s[u], (h mod 5) + 1);
    EncodeBuffer.Strings[h] := s;
  end;
end;

procedure TEncrypter.Decode;
var
  u, h: integer;
  s: String;
begin
  for h := 0 to EncodeBuffer.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := EncodeBuffer.Strings[h];
    for u := Low(s) to High(s) do
      s[u] := DecodeChar(s[u], (h mod 5) + 1);
    EncodeBuffer.Strings[h] := s;
  end;
end;
```

```
// FormCreate

var
  I, J, K, L: Integer;
  Temp: Array[32..126] of Char;
  NumInTemp: Integer;
begin
  ...

  for I := Low(Enc) to High(Enc) do
    Enc[I].Char := Char(I);

  for I := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    for J := Low(Temp) to High(Temp) do
      Temp[J] := Char(J);
    NumInTemp := Length(Temp);

    for J := Low(Enc) to High(Enc) do
    begin
      K := Low(Temp) + Random(NumInTemp);
      Enc[J].Enc[I] := Temp[K];
      for L := K+1 to (Low(Temp)+NumInTemp) do
        Temp[L-1] := Temp[L];
      Dec(NumInTemp);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And if you set up a separate decoder table instead of using `Enc[].Enc`, you can simplify `TEncrypter.DecodeChar()` to a similar lookup that `TEncrypter.EncodeChar()` uses, without having to use a loop at all.  I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: As for the string replace - I do use the Char[x] after Strings[x], so there should not be all occurrences replaced. Isn't this the way this works? :O
Because I was aware of that, but was looking a workaround...

Comment: As for the Char's replacements - the Enc[x].Enc[1] to Enc[x].Enc[5] are random, BUT unique. That's something I did check at creation; Also, there isn't any trouble telling which encode array to use, as, if you look at the long column (which calls the EncodeChar and DecodeChar function), it sends the Sign (char), and the Encoder (integer) to the function, so that it exactly knows by which enc array it must search and use as a key.

Comment: You did not show your initialization code, so we don't know that your arrays are unique.

Comment: True. They're long, that's why I avoided to put them in, unless it would be necessary, hence the last sentence, that I'll paste them if needed.

Comment: Anyway, your second part of the second code, where you lost the "h" conditions... you put in the mod, but don't check the actual line; is your version still for sure working in a way, so that the 1st, and every next 5th line are encoded by enc[x].enc[1], while the 2nd and 7th by enc[x].enc[2]... etc..? 
if so, which part orders that? I don't quite understand the shortcut you made... :/

Comment: `String.Replace()` replaces ALL occurrences. Internally, it calls `StringReplace()` with the `rfReplaceAll` flag.

Comment: Yes, this code works, I tested it before I posted it. Sounds like you have not yet learned what the [`mod` operator](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Mod) actually is or how it works. `0 mod 5` is 0, `1 mod 5` is 1, `2 mod 5` is 2, `3 mod 5` is 3, `4 mod 5` is 4, `5 mod 5` is 0, `6 mod 5` is 1, `7 mod 5` is 2, and so on. See how it wraps every 5th? Just like you wanted.

Comment: Yes, it replaces all occurrences INside of the GIVEN string. However, the string I'm passing to it is EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Chars[u], so it's basically always 1-char string... ;)
Nope, haven't actually worked with "mod" before... :/

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Now it's much clearer how/why it works...
Will change my code with that now...

Comment: You are assigning the replaced char back to the original string. Every time you call `Replace()`, you are re-searching the same source string over and over, not a 1-character string. You need to do some research and learn how `String.Replace()` actually works. Look at user1008646's answer, that is essentially what you are doing, why it does not work, and why I changed it in my answer to not use `Replace()` at all.

Comment: I don't get that one. With  
Replace(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Chars[u], EncodeChar(EncodeBuffer.Strings[h2].Chars[u], 2)) I passed the 1-char string to search through, and 1-char string to search for. So it's replacing 1 char with 1 char. How this couldn't work, as it actually does work for me?
It replaces just fine in Encode, exactly as it should. The decode part is where something get's lost though...

Comment: Added the key in a link (see Edit).

Comment: You are NOT searching a 1-character string. You are searching the entire `EncodeBuffer.Strings[h]` string and replacing all occurrences of `EncodeBuffer.Strings[h].Chars[u]` inside that string with the result of `EncodeChar()`.  `String.Replace()` does not replace a single `Char` in the string it is called on.  It replaces ALL matching `Char`s in the string.  The code I gave you eliminates `Replace()` and does a 1-to-1 character replacement, like you are expecting, in both encoding and decoding. Like I said, the code I gave you works, just try it.

Comment: `s := s.Replace(Char1, Char2)` is the same as `s := StringReplace(s, Char1, Char2, [rfReplaceAll])`. If you look in SysUtils.pas, you will see that is exactly how `TStringHelper.Replace(Char, Char)` is actually implemented: `Result := System.SysUtils.StringReplace(Self, OldChar, NewChar, [rfReplaceAll]);`

Comment: Well, I thought that if the first parameter is the string IN WHICH I search, and if I set that string to be basically only one char, it would actually look through that "string", and so it would found only one char. I guess I understood wrong, how to define the string to search through... :/

Comment: And yes, I did understood wrong indeed. Just as you said, it did change char by char, at least in the watchlist seemed so, but actually did the conversion on the whole string -.- :/

Also thanks for the mod. Code is much nicer now!
From the bottom of my heart. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I start with a string "abc".

I want to replace all "a" with "c", replace all "b" with "Q", and replace all "c" with "7".
Perhaps I would write:

```
S := 'abc';
S := S . Replace ( 'a', 'c' );
S := S . Replace ( 'b', 'Q' );
S := S . Replace ( 'c', '7' );
```

The result is '7Q7'.  Oops!  Why wasn't "a" replaced with "c"?
Well, it was. 
After the first call to Replace, S was 'cbc'.
After the second call, S was 'cQc'.
The last call replaced both 'c's with '7'.

I imagine you are doing the same sort of thing here. 
I couldn't give you the specific results of your code character for character unless we saw how you were populating the Enc structure.

Comment: No, I'm not. That's why there's a Break in my "for" loops, on the short procedures (EncodeChars, DecodeChars). So, that's not the case :/

Comment: Added the "key" in a link (see Edit above).

Comment: And yes, you were right as well as Remy! I thought the code did the conversion of only one char as I put a parameter .char[x] in it, but apparently did not do what I thought it does. Good observation! (Y) :)
Thanks.