# Delphi - procedure fails to complete, but works fine with "showmessage" between.?

Tags: delphi

I'm not quite sure how to even ask this question, since I don't know whether it is related to the execution time, application process.message procedure or anything else.

I'm having (for me) weird situations, where the procedure fails to run and raises system exception on run, while it runs completely flawless if I put "showmessage" there in between (which I put so that I could quickly see what's going on in between. I prefer that way over watches somehow...).

I'm not sure whether the code matters or not, but I'll give it below:

```
procedure LoadSettings;
var SettingsBuffToLoad: TStringList;
begin
  SettingsBuffToLoad:=TStringList.Create;
  Encoding:=TEncoding.ANSI;
  SettingsBuffToLoad.LoadFromFile('bin/settings.txt', Encoding);
//  showmessage(settingsbufftoload.Strings[0]);
  SettingsBuffer:=Decode(SettingsBuffToLoad);
//  showmessage(settingsbuffer.Strings[0]);  //decode
end;
```

The Decode procedure is declared as external and is read from the dll.

If I just remove those "/" , so that it becomes the code instead of comment, it works just fine. However, set as you see now, it raises exception, but after the procedure is already done. (the debugger last break point is stopped at "end;", after continuing however it raises exception instead of showing the form; this procedure is called as the last thing in FormCreate procedure.

Is there anything that has to do with the timing, which ShowMessage solves, or...? :/

Update:
The decode functions, as asked:

this is how it's declared, right above of the implementation and variables of the form:

function Decode(Buff: TStringList): TStringList; StdCall; external 'bin\settings.txt';

And this is in the dll:

```
function Decode(Buff: TStringList): TStringList; export;
var
t, u, h: integer;
s: String;
begin
DecodeBuffer.Clear;
DecodeBuffer:=Buff;
  for h := 0 to DecodeBuffer.Count-1 do
  begin
    s := DecodeBuffer.Strings[h];
    t := Length(s);
    if t > 0 then
    begin
      for u := 0 to t-1 do
      begin
        s[u+1] := DecodeChar(s[u+1], (h mod 5) + 1);
      end;
      DecodeBuffer.Strings[h] := s;
    end;
  end;
Result:=DecodeBuffer;
end;
```

This code was discussed in a question at [Delphi changing Chars in string - missunderstood behavior - XE3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313902/delphi-changing-chars-in-string-missunderstood-behavior-xe3) and is used from Remy's answer. The DecodeChar is, I believe simply unimportant here, or is it?

Also, the same goes with the function to save settings, which is called at FormClose event:

This is:

```
procedure TScribbles.SaveSettings;
var SettingsBuffToSave: TStringList;
begin
  SettingsBuffToSave:=TStringList.Create;
  Encoding := TEncoding.ANSI;
//  Showmessage(settingsbuffer.Strings[0]);
  SettingsBuffToSave:=Encode(SettingsBuffer);
//  Showmessage(settingsbufftosave.Strings[0]);
  SettingsBuffToSave.SaveToFile('bin/settings.txt', Encoding);
end;
```

With the first ShowMessage used as code instead of comment, it works, while otherwise in a comment function as it is written above, it calls external exception the same way as on Decode.
Is it possible, that the SettingsBuffToSave is just not yet created when it already calls the function Encode, or what?
At that time, the SettingsBuffer exists and is populated, so it really seems weird that it raises errors, which disappears with simply putting ShowMessage in there.

(Function Encode is basically a mirror of Decode, so the code is not important here...)

Comment: If we don't know anything about the Decode function, it's pretty much impossible to help you solve this problem. What is the DLL function declaration? What parameter is it expecting, and what type is it returning? Without that information, you're asking us to just guess what might possibly be wrong, and you can do that yourself.

Comment: What does Decode return? Who's responsible for what it returns? How's it destroyed?

Comment: I expected I might need to post more code... That's as I said, I don't know what is going on and where it stops..
However, @Ken, Decode function is declared as external, stdcall, expects TStringList and returns exactly the same. It was discussed in another of my question here, and it just swaps the chars in each string of a stringlist.
I'm sorry if it looks like I want you to guess, I just don't really know how much I should post, as there is quite a lot of code behind, and, as said, it simply works good if I put a simple ShowMessage between, what doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz what do you mean by "who's responsible for what it returns" and "how it's destroyed"?
The function is simply declared as an external, and is just called afterwards. The same goes with Encode function on FromClose event, which has basically the same trouble; with showmessage it just works. I'm updating the question with Decode function ;

Comment: @Just - My query involves what's passed over module boundary, does the dll hand the executable a string or a class etc and how its lifetime is managed. Not how the function is declared or the like. Your question and David's answer now include relevant details/information.

Comment: @JustMarc: It's a little unreasonable to expect us to check your profile to see if you'd provided details in a previous question. It's much easier if you include that information ("I asked before about this code") and include a link to your previous post so we can find it.

Comment: @Ken I did include the link in my question. See section right bellow the second code-paragraph please.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, but that was well after I made my first comment. :-) If you had included it from the start, I would not have needed to leave that comment, which is why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is VERY VERY VERY dangerous on many levels.  Using objects across the DLL boundary in an unsafe manner.  Mismanagement of object pointers across function calls.  You need a redesign.  Try the following as a start:

```
procedure Decode(Buff: PChar; BuffLen: Integer; ListIndex: Integer); stdcall; export;
var
  u: integer;
begin
  for u := 0 to BuffLen-1 do
  begin
    Buff^ := DecodeChar(Buff^, (ListIndex mod 5) + 1);
    Inc(Buff);
  end;
end;

procedure Encode(Buff: PChar; BuffLen: Integer; ListIndex: Integer); stdcall; export;
var
  u: integer;
begin
  for u := 0 to BuffLen-1 do
  begin
    Buff^ := EncodeChar(Buff^, (ListIndex mod 5) + 1);
    Inc(Buff);
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure Decode(Buff: PChar; BuffLen: Integer; ListIndex: Integer); stdcall; external '...';

procedure Encode(Buff: PChar; BuffLen: Integer; ListIndex: Integer); stdcall; external '...';

procedure LoadSettings;
var
  h: Integer;
begin
  SettingsBuffer := TStringList.Create;
  SettingsBuffer.LoadFromFile('bin/settings.txt', TEncoding.ANSI);
  for h := 0 to SettingsBuff.Count-1 do
  begin
    Decode(PChar(SettingsBuff[h]), Length(SettingsBuff[h]), h);
  end;
end;

procedure TScribbles.SaveSettings;
var
  h: Integer;
begin
  for h := 0 to SettingsBuff.Count-1 do
  begin
    Encode(PChar(SettingsBuff[h]), Length(SettingsBuff[h]), h);
  end;
  SettingsBuff.SaveToFile('bin/setpb95enc.dll', TEncoding.ANSI);
end;
```

Comment: The code in this answer is nice. I think I'd avoid using the word dangerous here. That implies that the code in the Q is valid, but error prone. It is certainly not valid as I know you recognise.

Comment: Why is this dangerous? I mean, what is the difference if I pass the whole stringlist agains every line? Isn't that also doable with my code redesign, so that I'm passing it as strings? Why is PChar better?

Comment: Also, why is this redesign much different and better than the one that you answered in your other answer (in the topic, linked in my question)? As @David stated, that I should put the whole code in the exe instead, is this redesign than good to still keep in dll?

Comment: For the PChar I think I got the answer from @David's comments.... For the rest, looking forward for your opinion.

Comment: I somehow can't manage to get this answer/code work. I get access violation errors, on both, load and save calls. (also, the second file at save is settings.txt for the matter of a question. I changed that only for this question, but forgot it when updating the question code. Otherwise the setpb95enc.dll is just a settings.txt renamed, so that its not appearing as text file... Uops... )

Comment: @JustMarc The code in the answer is fine. It's your code that is broken. Did you follow the advice I gave you. In particular did you do items 4 and 5 in my answer? In both EXE and DLL?

Comment: @JustMarc,: the code I gave you in the other question was not designed to be used across a DLL boundary. That adds a whole new layer of complexity to the situation. It is not safe to use objects, strings, and other dynamic/managed types across the boundary, unless both EXE and DLL are compiled to use the same RTL, the same memory manager, etc by enabling ShareMem, runtime packages, etc. Otherwise, matching memory layouts/semantics are not guaranteed. By switching to a PCbar param, it passes a pointer directly to the character data, avoiding any memory management/layout issues.

Comment: @JustMarc: there are plenty of blogs, articles, etc that explain DLL interop issues in more detail, especially when it comes to passing string parameters, which are very common in DLL programming.

Comment: @Remy thanks, now I see that, and as said, I get why PChar is used from David's answer. However, this exact code doesn't run in my program. I completely removed all of my code that is in the dll, and every piece in exe that was previously communicating with it. But it throws access violations. :/
Argh, I guess I'll just go without the dll. It will be the best afterall..
I just really thought I'm doing it the right way, and that there is simple (or better said Logical!) explanation why the ShowMessage, that reads from the buffer, solves the thing. If the showmessage is random string ('hello')

Comment: it still doesn't work. Just if it reads the buffer itself. Sorry for bothering and thanks for solutions!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem here is that the code exists in a DLL. Most likely you didn't arrange for the DLL to share its host's heap. And a Delphi class cannot be passed across a DLL boundary.

If you want to share Delphi classes between modules, you must use packages. Of course, another option is to put all the code in the same module. That is remove the DLL, and compile everything in the executable. The final option is to use valid interop types for DLLs.

Of course, there could be other reasons for the actual error. The code smells bad. For instance, what is this:

```
DecodeBuffer:=Buff;
```

Is `DecodeBuffer` a global variable? If so then it is plausible that you refer to the object after it has been destroyed. Not that I can see evidence of anything being destroyed. Without wishing to seem rude, your code looks like it may have multiple problems. As a matter of urgency you need to:

1. Deal with the DLL problem described above.
2. Remove global variables.
3. Fix lifetime issues. Stop leaking.
4. Enable range checking to locate buffer overruns.
5. Add FastMM in debug mode to try to catch heap corruptions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that I didn't arrange the DLL to share its host's heap? What you also mean that delphi class cannot be passed across a dll? Why then it works as it should, when using something like ShowMessage somewhere between, and what it changes in the code?
How can it be of such a vital meaning here?

Comment: Oh, and DecodeBuffer:=Buf -> this was due to the other topic/question suggestion by Remy, that I need to make sort of a "copy" of the buffer (stringlist) before doing anything with it. Therefore I'm doing just that. The DecodeBuffer:=TStringList.Create is declared within the dll itself!, and is not passed as a global variable; It is created in the Begin section of a dll, so AFAIK when the dll is loaded first time, and I'm calling it's destruction (.Free) after everything is already done; It's the last thing that an app does at destruction. After SaveSettings procedure;

Comment: Sure as hell after LoadSettings (as this is the first procedure called at app start).
Is it possible, that I'm calling that procedure in LoadSettings, before the dll is actually fully initialized? I mean, really, what a difference makes that ShowMessage, except for the code pausing from continuing execution?

Comment: @JustMarc `DecodeBuffer:=Buf` does not copy the buffer. It takes a reference to the string list object. What else do you do with `DecodeBuffer`. Now, sharing heap is achieved by using `Sharemem`. That won't help you very much though. Because you cannot pass a Delphi class across a DLL boundary. Delphi classes are not valid for DLL interop. You need simple types such as you might find in, for example, Windows APIs.

Comment: *Is it possible, that I'm calling that procedure in LoadSettings, before the dll is actually fully initialized?* No it is not. You are going to need to take a deep breath and contemplate the possibility that what I am telling you is true. You cannot pass Delphi classes across DLL boundaries.

Comment: The way I think about this is that in your executable you have a class named `TStringList`. In the DLL you have a class named `TStringList`. They are not the same class. They have the same name. They have methods that have the same names. But they are different classes. You might, by chance, get away with calling functions like this. Sometimes. But it's wrong. You have to stop passing Delphi classes across a DLL boundary. This has been discussed many many times before in many different places.

Comment: Ok, I get that, and I fully believe you. So basically the PChar in @Remy's answer bellow is there because StringList is not valid WinApi class, correct?
Still, just curious, why it actually does work with ShowMessage?

Comment: Yes, @Remy is passing interop friendly types because of the limitation that I have described. As I said, I don't really agree with his use of the word "dangerous". The issue is more serious than that. Why does it work when you throw in a `ShowMessage`? Who knows? Perhaps there are other errors beyond the one that Remy and I have pointed out. We cannot see all of the code. And when you invoke undefined behaviour like this, predicting what happens is very hard. Undefined behaviour is inherently unpredictable.

Comment: I urge you to carry out all five itemised steps in my answer. They are all important.

Comment: ok. I kust thought there is some deeper explanation of what the ShowMessage in there changes. If its just randomly "it made the code work" part of inserted code, than I guess my question is out of the matter. I need to change the whole concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on here:  I think your stack is getting smashed.

Furthermore, I rather suspect the actual cause is the Decode procedure using an uninitialized variable.  Your ShowMessage statement (it would be the first one that matters if I'm right) changes what's on the stack and thus changes the uninitialized variable.

If I'm right this is going to have some heisenbug attributes--anything you do to find out what's going on will change the value of the uninitialized variable.

One thing to try:  Declare a large local variable (the idea is to use up stack space) and make sure it's not discarded by the compiler.  This will move things in memory and thus likely defuse the blowup.  If it works it's pretty conclusive at to what's going on.

Comment: Yes, it's the firstone that makes the differenfce; If it's not called, I get the "External exception: C000001D.
Now what I don't understand is, why there's the same behaviour at FormClose event with Encode function?
Check the function in my updated question.
At that time, all of the variables should've already been initialized!

Comment: Funny, I thought it was a Schroedingbug